# Quote (proverb like structure) of knowing one's options

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, quotes

I'm looking for a quote to use in a sentence that says if it's free and doesn't cost anything to know your options (like a free estimate to a customer) then it can't hurt to find out. And that knowing your options in life is very important.

Answer (score 3):

The *it can't hurt to find out* part reminds me of the saying:

> *There is no harm in asking.*

This uses the ***there is no harm*** idiom:

> Doing something may be good, pragmatic, or beneficial, and will not cause any problems or harm
>   
> <sub>[The Free Dictionary by Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/there+is+no+harm+in)</sub>

The *knowing your options is important* part reminds me of the cliché:

> *You should always look before you leap.*

Which uses the ***look before you leap*** idiom:

> Think carefully about what you are about to do before you do it.
>   
> <sub>[The Free Dictionary by Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+before+you+leap)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The first, “it can't hurt to find out,” notion reminds me of [“It costs nothing to ask”](https://books.google.com/books?id=AbJ1tVGmiTgC&pg=PR64&lpg=PR64&dq=%22it+costs+nothing+to+ask%22&source=bl&ots=1HABf30m_z&sig=CdeuKyEdjX0BV9ps1RiRNDQck3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPjs3wjo7eAhVB6VMKHbztBTE4ChDoATADegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=%22it%20costs%20nothing%20to%20ask%22&f=false), and its variation (f): “You lose nothing by asking, and there is a chance to gain something lasting.”

(from *A Dictionary of American Proverbs*,  By Wolfgang Mieder, via *Google Books*)

You could use those two as follows:

> It costs nothing to ask us about your options.

or

> You’ll lose nothing by asking us about your options, and you’ll
>   [even/probably] have  much/something to gain.

---

As for “knowing your options is important,” maybe you could flip and play upon the inverse of the ideas expressed by:
[“Ignorance is bliss”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignorance_is_bliss) (from *wiktionary.org*) or
[“What you don't know can't hurt you”](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What+you+don%27t+know+can%27t+hurt+you) (from *thefreedictionary.com*), as follows:

> When it comes to (knowing your) options, ignorance is NOT bliss (and
>   it costs nothing to ask us about yours).
>
> There’s nothing blissful about not knowing/being ignorant about one’s
>   options.  (You’ll lose nothing by asking us to help discover yours, and
>   you’ll [even/probably] have much/something to gain.)
>
> What you don’t know about your options CAN hurt you (and it costs
>   nothing to ask us to help you find out all you need to know).
>
> Not knowing your options will cost/hurt you much more than asking for
>   our free, no-obligation estimate/consultation.

Comment: I would use *knowledge is power* as the flip to *ignorance is bliss*.

Comment: @jxh Nice catch! Not only is *knowledge is power* the best flip to *ignorance is bliss*, it's also a stand-alone winner on its own. +1, both here and where it counts.